# How to use filter for multiple fields in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to apply filter to multiple fields in a table ,in html code I have a single textbox for searching

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> <input type="text" placeholder="Search " ng-model="search">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    app.controller('myController', function($scope) {$scope.employee = [
{ empid: 1, empname: 'saisree', division:'IS',mgr:'A',clientlocation:'PA' },
{ empid: 2, empname: 'poojitha', division:'IS',mgr:'A',clientlocation:'PA' },
{ empid: 3, empname: 'shyam', division:'IS',mgr:'A',clientlocation:'PA'},
{empid: 4, empname: 'shariff', division:'IS',mgr:'A',clientlocation:'PA'},
{empid: 5, empname: 'anvita', division:'GIS',mgr:'B',clientlocation:'AZ'},
{empid: 6, empname: 'poojitha';`division:'Retail',mgr:'C'clientlocation:'UK';];});
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="e in employee | filter:search ">
    <td>{{ e.empid }}</td>
    <td>{{ e.empname }}</td>
    <td>{{ e.division }}</td>
     <td>{{ e.mgr }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.clientlocation }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The user should be able to search from a single textbox by giving empid,empname,division,mgr,clientloaction. please look into this issue.

This is the table that I'm applying filter to, but giving search in the filter applies to all columns at a time!

Comment: where is the table that you are applying the filter to?  You only show the input box and the sample data here, you aren't showing the display portion.

Comment: Hi Thank you I have updated the code please look into it!

Comment: so are you wanting to provide some sort of radio button or dropdown to restrict the search to a single column?

Comment: It is a single textbox. Consider i have huge amount of data and in the text box i want to give multiple fileds for example both empname, division so that i get the exact match from the table

Comment: so you want to type the name of the field in the textbox that you want to search from, along with the search term?  Your question is still not really clear....

Comment: I mean, from what you are saying in the comments, you are wanting to do something like `"shariff, IS"` and have it find the right row, but how would it know that `"shariff"` is the `empname` field just from that? what if someone put `"poojitha, UK"`, how is it supposed to know that `UK` is `clientlocation`?

Comment: can i share my plunker link so that u can get an idea? only if its ok!

Comment: you'll definitely have to share something else to clarify what you are trying to do, because right now, it's not clear.  searching all the fields is the default way filter works, and doing selective searches of specific fields requires quite a bit of logic to work out.

Comment: hi claies, actually what u said is right,if i have only one search field it would not know which is the empname and which is the location ,so i have done it using different search fields!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
<label>your input: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>

<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="e in employee |filter:search:strict ">
    <td>{{ e.empid }}</td>
    <td>{{ e.empname }}</td>
    <td>{{ e.division }}</td>
     <td>{{ e.mgr }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.clientlocation }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That will match any key e.g if you want to filter by .empid or .empname etc.. it will filter that

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do the wrong way its working fine now!

Comment: I still don't see how this is any different from the default behavior;  it's still searching all fields simultaneously.